# como puedo hacer que un if reconozca una variable de con un rango numérico en C#?

Tags: c#

algo de este estilo:

```
string var1 = "X1";
string var2 = "X2";
string var3 = "X3";
string var4 = "X4";
string linea = Console.ReadLine(); 
if (charla.Contains([seria intentar que aquí reconociera el rango de 
variables de X1 a X4]));
```

soy nuevo aquí así que perdonad si todavía no se muy bien como van las cosas.

Comment: Échale un ojo a la funcion `.intersec`

Comment: Hola @oscuro08. Lo que debería hacer es mirar si contiene alguna variable? Has pensado en hacer un array en vez de 4 variables? así con un bucle lo podrías recorrer sin problemas

Comment: he conseguido declarar el array pero sigo sin conseguir que la funcion detecte un valor cualquiera del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacerlo con un array se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
string[] vars = {"X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"}; //Declaramos el array con los valores a buscar

string linea = Console.ReadLine(); //Leemos la línea por teclado
bool encontrado = false; //Declaramos una variable booleana para indicar si hemos encontrado coincidencia o no

for(int i=0; i<vars.Length; i++){  //Con este bucle recorremos el array
    if(linea.Contains(vars[i]))  //Comprobamos si la línea contiene lo que tiene el array en la posición i
    {
        encontrado = true; //Si lo contiene, pasamos encontrado a true
    }
}

if(encontrado == true)  //Si encontrado es true lo imprimimos por pantalla
    MessageBox.Show("Encontrado!", "Éxito");
```

Comment: Como sugerencia...si haces el `if` al reves, te ahorras el bucle for: `if (vars.Contains(linea))
            {
                encontrado = true;
            }`

Comment: Yo diría que no funciona, vamos, he probado y no me ha encontrado la coincidencia

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9LGwXq

Comment: Eso solo valdría si línea es exactamente "X1" o "X2" o "X3" o "X4", si línea es "X1 hola" por ejemplo, ya no lo va a encontrar.

Comment: En ese caso, se podría usar `Intersect` con un `Split`, algo como `if (vars.Intersect(linea.Split(' ')).Count()>0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
   string var1 = "X1";
   string var2 = "X2";
   string var3 = "X3";
   string var4 = "X4";
   //Creamos una lista para introducir los valores var1....
   List<string> list = new List<string>();   
   list.add(var1); list.add(var2); list.add(var3); list.add(var4);
   //Aquí tendrás todos tus valores en una lista llamada list

    string[] coincidencias= null;//crear una variable para guardar las coincidencias

  coincidencias = charla.ToList() //Obtienes en coincidencias los valores que  
            .Intersect(list)      //coincidan de la lista
            .ToArray();
```